# Group by in Spring data rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

Does spring data rest provide default support for group by or having clauses using query dsl ? I know it allows filtering and sorting but does it allow aggregation by default?

Comment: Seraching for an answer to the very same question, this is the first result on google =) I suppose, no, it doesn't. At least I couldn't find any references to that.